# assign unique ID name to unique rows with multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, unique, data.table

I apologize, not sure how to insert a data.table into the question box.

I have a data set with a ton of rows like this:

```
phylum class family order genus species
A      B     C      D     E     NA
A      B     C      D     E     NA
A      B     C      D     NA    NA
A      B     C      D     E     F
A      B     C      D     NA    NA
A      B     C      D     E     F
```

I would like each matching row to be assigned a unique ID for example:

```
 ID phylum class family order genus species
 1  A      B     C      D     E     NA
 1  A      B     C      D     E     NA
 2  A      B     C      D     NA    NA
 3  A      B     C      D     E     F
 2  A      B     C      D     NA    NA
 3  A      B     C      D     E     F
```

I have tried using GRP in a variety of ways but its not working. 
For example:
DT2 = DT[,i:=.GRP,by=key(DT)]

I have looked at other samples but everything is assigning IDs based on a single or only 2 columns value and I want to use 6 different ones. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's `key(DT)` here? `:=` assigns by reference. You don't need to assign it back to `DT2` btw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution with base R:

```
df2 <- unique(df)
df2$ID <- 1:nrow(df2)
merge(df, df2)
```

---

or using `data.table`:

```
dt[, ID := .GRP, by = names(dt)]
```

Comment: There is no way to do this in one fall swoop? I just have so many columns I have to remove in order to do it this way. If I could specify which columns to use for unique identification that would help.

Comment: try `df2<-unique(df[,tokeep])` where `tokeep` is an array indicating which columns you want to keep.

Comment: Does this mean, all other columns will be discarded? I just want to mark those taxa that are similar but keep the columns specifying were they come from and how many were seen. Plus a few other things.

Comment: Did you try to execute those commands? No, the columns won't be descarded. The `tokeep` columns just definy the unique rows. First you define a new dataframe with just the column that define a unique value, than you assign the id and finally you merge the old data frame with the new one.

Comment: Thanks Nicola. I did it that way but was wondering if there was a way to not have to generate and merge two different files. I'll do it this way for now. Thanks again.